# How can I add a display name to a component defined in an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am trying to render React components to a view. The view is a dashboard. The dashboard has a sidebar, header, and main component. The sidebar contains links which when clicked renders the matched component to the main view. The main view is the one that re-renders.

I am using react-router to render the various links that the dashboard entails by iterating over them and determining which nav link is clicked. I am iterating over the routes using a map.

The routes array of route objects.

```
export const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        exact: true,
        main: () => <Home />
    },
    {
        path: "/company",
        exact: true,
        main: () => <Company />
    },
    {
        path: "/comments",
        exact: true,
        main: () => <Comments />
    }
]
```

Displaying the routes:

```
{routes.map(route => (
    <Route
        key={route.path}
        path={route.path}
        exact={route.exact}
        component={route.main}
     />
))}
```

I expect the routes to be rendered to the main component as desired i.e when the navigation links on the sidebar are clicked. The error I am encountering is this: **Component definition is missing display name react/display-name** on the line where I have the key *main*: `main: () => <Company />`.

Comment: Why is main a function?

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer That is the name I chose for the view in my grid. The main grid is responsible for the dashboard details view e.g company table, comments table, etc.

Comment: Got it, but `component` expects a jsx element not a function, so try to just assign `<Home />` etc. to main (like `main: <Home />` not as a function), Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

main should not be a function in this case.
Try without a function or call the main function.

```js
{routes.map(route => (
    <Route
        key={route.path}
        path={route.path}
        exact={route.exact}
        component={route.main()}
     />
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the same pattern as you in my case my routes variable looks like this:

```
export const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        exact: true,
        main: Home
    },
    {
        path: "/company",
        exact: true,
        main: Company
    },
    {
        path: "/comments",
        exact: true,
        main: Comments
    }
]
```

EDIT: this is how I use it

```js
routes.map(ROUTE => (
  <Route
    key={ROUTE.url}
    path={ROUTE.url}
    exact
    component={ROUTE.component}
    // In case you want to add props to the component
    // render={props => <ROUTE.component path={ROUTE.url} {...props} />}
  />
))
```

Comment: When declaring components as you have demonstrated, how do you ensure that they are rendered?

Comment: Like this: ```routes.map(r => <Route key={r.url} path={r.url} exact component={r.component} />```